# Cost function increasing in multivariate linear regression

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm a beginner in machine learning and I'm trying to implement a multivariate linear regression algorithm. Below is the code I've come up with. It runs without error however the cost function is increasing.
[Here's the cost function graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPprf.png)
[Here is the dataset I used](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_pZuHQMTAfqR2RxbNWZ5uFIbWovnyz0O/view?usp=sharing)

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
def h(j):
    s = 0
    for i in range(len(t)):
        s+=t[i] * X[i][j]
    return s
def J(j):
    s=0
    for i in range(len(Y)):
        s+= (h(i) - Y[i])**2
    return s/(2*len(Y))
def g():
    temp = []
    s    = []
    for i in range(len(t)):
        temp.append(0)
        s.append(0)
    for j in range(len(t)):
        for i in range(len(Y)):
            s[j]+= (h(i) - Y[i])*X[j][i]
    for i in range(len(t)):
        temp[i] = alpha * (1/len(Y)) * s[i]
    return temp[0],temp[1],temp[2] 
alpha = 0.0000000000001
epochs = 100
data = pd.read_csv("ex1data2.txt")
X = np.empty(shape = (3,10))
X[0] = [ 1.00000000e+00,1.00000000e+00,1.00000000e+00 ,1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00 , 1.00000000e+00 , 1.00000000e+00  ,1.00000000e+00,
   1.00000000e+00 , 1.00000000e+00 ]
X[1] = [ 1.31415422e-01, -5.09640698e-01,  5.07908699e-01, -7.43677059e-01,
   1.27107075e+00 ,-1.99450507e-02, -5.93588523e-01 ,-7.29685755e-01,
  -7.89466782e-01 ,-6.44465993e-01 ]
X[2] = [-2.26093368e-01, -2.26093368e-01, -2.26093368e-01 ,-1.55439190e+00,
   1.10220517e+00 , 1.10220517e+00 ,-2.26093368e-01 ,-2.26093368e-01,
  -2.26093368e-01 ,-2.26093368e-01 ]
t = [0,0,0]
Y = [ 399900,329900,369000,232000,539900,299900,314900,198999,212000,242500]
stdevs = [0]
means  = [1]
for i in range(np.shape(X)[0]):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    else:
        means.append(np.mean(X[i]))
        X[i] = X[i] - means[i]
        stdevs.append(np.std(X[i]))
        X[i] = X[i] / stdevs[i]
costs = []
for i in range(epochs):
    costs.append(J(i))
    t[0],t[1],t[2] = g()
plt.plot(range(len(costs)),costs)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you include your data as a numpy array so we can run the code? Just extract maybe 10 samples from your dataset. Also, if you want to do machine learning, learn how to use vectorization, it is much more efficient: https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how I would do that and make the script executable within stackoverflow if that's what you mean when you said "so we can run the code"

Comment: I adjusted the code so that you don't need the data.